# Threading in a Python Gtk Application

Tags: python, gtk, python-multithreading, glade

I am trying to create a program that displays the positional data from a gyroscope. I have been using the threading.Thread module for this purpose. I also have to use the time.sleep() to prevent it from crashing right off the bat. My problem is after it has been running for a while the program will sometimes freeze. It is implemented something like this:

```
def get_gyro_data():
    return <the data from the gyro>

class Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = builder.get_object("my_label")
        threading.Thread(target=self.pos_data_update).start()

    def pos_data_update(self, *args):
        while True:
            self.label.set_text(get_gyro_data())
            time.sleep(.5)
```

Any suggestions? Also is there a way I can do this without using time.sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gtk is not thread safe. All changes to the GUI should be made from the main thread (the one that runs the mainloop).

I like to use the following function:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib

def mainloop_do(callback, *args, **kwargs):
    def cb(_None):
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
        return False
    Gdk.threads_add_idle(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, cb, None)
```

This allows you to pass the work to the main thread with minimal changes to your code:

```
def pos_data_update(self, *args):
    while True:
        mainloop_do(self.label.set_text, get_gyro_data())
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to use this function:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 25, in cb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 25, in cb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @DanielCopley Sounds like you passed a tuple as the `callback` parameter. I use this function regularly, I'm sure it works.

Comment: Ok well I realized what I was doing wrong there, I had inserted "self" into the mainloop_do parameters, but it still freezes now when I run it. I need this to update the labels while the program continues to run.

Comment: Do I still start the pos_data_update() function with a Thread()?

Comment: @DanielCopley Yes, this should allow the function to work from within a thread. I'm not sure why your program is still freezing. Maybe your main thread is busy executing an event handler? Or if you have an old version of Gtk/GObject, you may have to call `GObject.threads_init()`.

Comment: @Rawing How is this better than a simple `GLib.timeout_add_seconds (5, get_gyro_data())` ?

Comment: @theGtknerd It's better if you do more work than just updating a label and sleeping. If you don't have a timeout, it saves you the trouble of specifying a `priority`, and it supports keyword arguments. But you're right that `timeout_add` is a better choice if the code is as short as here.